# Flutter PDF Viewer shows only white pages

Tags: flutter, pdf, pdf-viewer

I'm trying to display a PDF file in Flutter which I have previously downloaded from a server.
I have tried both flutter_full_pdf_viewer and advance_pdf_viewer. Both libs show me the correct number of pages, but the pages are all white.

Does anybody have an idea why? makes no difference if I run it on iOS or Android or in emulator or real device.

```
class _PdfPageState extends State<PdfPage> {

  String pathPDF = "";

  File file;
  PDFDocument doc = null;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WeeklyReportsRepository( userRepository: UserRepository()).loadWeeklyReport(widget.weeklyReport.filename).then((file) {
        setDoc(file);
    });
  }

  Future<void> setDoc(File file) async {
    var doc1 = await PDFDocument.fromFile(file);
    setState(() {
      doc = doc1;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
        title: Text(
          "Wochenbericht",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Theme
            .of(context)
            .backgroundColor,
      child: (doc == null) ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) :
        PDFViewer(document: doc,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems right but can you try to view a pdf from your computer or a link and also try to view specific page of the pdf. [Package document](https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer) try load from assets, URL, or file as shown in the link if these ways work you have a problem from server side.

Comment: hello, thanks for the tip. It wasn't the library but the downloading of the file.

Comment: I am happy to help you ))

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is the file name which was in UTF-8 characters. Once I changed the pdf file name to english letters, `advance_pdf_viewer` can read it with or without .pdf extension.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Pdf File is alphabet file, not a pic converted to a pdf.